# Is Haskell's STM `check` different from explicitly using `retry`?

Tags: haskell, stm

I am experimenting with STM by implementing the dining philsophers problems.

Anyway, I have the following definitions.

```
data ChopStick = CS (TVar Bool)

takeChopstick :: ChopStick -> STM ()
takeChopstick (CS chopstick) = do
    isTaken <- readTVar chopstick
    check (isTaken)
    writeTVar chopstick True
```

This function is called atomically:

```
atomically $ do
    takeChopstick leftChopstick
    takeChopstick rightChopstick
```

When running the program with the above definition of takeChopstick, I experience different results to running it with this definition:

```
takeChopstick :: ChopStick -> STM ()
takeChopstick (CS chopstick) = do
    isTaken <- readTVar chopstick
    if isTaken
        then retry
        else writeTVar chopstick True
```

In particular, the program hangs.

The source code for `check` (hackage, stm-2.2.0.1) is as follows:

```
check :: Bool -> STM a
check b = if b then return undefined else retry
```

Which appears to be effectively the same as my explicit use of `retry`.

How does `check` differ to explicitly using `retry`? Is pushing the `retry` call further down causing it to restart a different atomic block?

Comment: You have your `then`/`else` swapped compared to `check`.

Comment: Oh dear, of course it's that obvious! Thanks @DanielWagner

Comment: @CodeMonkey Perhaps write your own answer to the question and accept it so it doesn't appear open any more.

Comment: @PetrPudlák good idea, I've added my own answer but can't accept for 2 days.

Answer (score 3):

No, `check` is no different than to using `retry` explicitly, I simply confused the argument to `check`.

The solution is to `check` that `isTaken` is `False`, i.e., `check $ not isTaken`.

```
takeChopstick :: ChopStick -> STM ()
takeChopstick (CS chopstick) = do
    isTaken <- readTVar chopstick
    check (not isTaken)
    writeTVar chopstick True
```